# 500 Error on index.php file. All other php files are working well

Tags: lamp, php

I've successfully installed LAMP and created some virtual hosts. Everything is working fine except index.php files.

When I try access them, browser returns 500 Error, regardless of their content. All other PHP files are working fine, index.html files can be opened without any errors. Please, help me to resolve this problem. I guess something wrong with server configuration, but I didn't find what exactly.

Comment: Please add the fullpath to where your index.php file is located and also the output of the shell command `ls -l /fullpath/to/index.php` . Press ctrl+alt+t to open a terminal. Also add the content of the index.php file you are trying.

Comment: Try open a shell and type `php foo.php` and `php -l foo.php`. You may also check your settings with the script `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: The fullpath of my index file is: /home/stas/projects/dreamsblock/index.php

Comment: Here is the result of ls - l command: -rw------- 1 stas stas 241 2011-11-21 13:31

Comment: The contents of index.php file is simply: <?php echo 'test'; ?>. I checked the settings with phpinfo(); but they seems ok. Could you suggest me what exact setting I should check?

Comment: How can you get a 500 (internal server error) when the web server cannot read the file? Is your web server running as stas?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue. The problem was with CHMOD of my virtual host directory. I set chmod value to 755 and it began to work :)). Sorry for bothering with such stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check Apache error log:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

That would give you some hints