# 500 Error on index.php file

Tags: apache2, php, localhost

I have found a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81471/500-error-on-index-php-file-all-other-php-files-are-working-well) very similar to this, which I thought would solve my problem.

However, after changing my .htaccess file, with index.php on the end of the list, and then index.php as the only entry, I still cannot get index.php to display.  Every other page works fine, but I don't know how to fix this.  Thanks.

Comment: Check your logs for helpful detail:  `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @LarsRohrbach Upon starting Apache2, it says this:
 "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0." As well as this for when I try to load index.php: "[Sat Nov 10 21:54:04 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in /var/www/index.php on line 1
"

Comment: The contents of index.php itself may be the problem -- you may have a quoting issue on line 1, or perhaps left off the `;` at the end.

Comment: @LarsRohrbach Ah, that was the issue.  I simply copy and paste the basic layout for new sites I make, and I accidentally had an invalid, old screw-up.  I feel stupid for not looking there before, so thank you for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a 500 error, you'll always want to start with checking your logs, in this case:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

You commented that the error log indicated:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in /var/www/index.php on line 1

This indicates that the content of `index.php` itself is likely the problem.  Check line 1 for either a quoting issue of some sort (wrong number of quotes?) or perhaps the `;` was left off the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

> I think there may be any mistake at **.htaccess** file

The following resources may help you to resolve the issue

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540310/internal-error-500-with-htaccess-file
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348999/confounding-htaccess-errors-leading-to-error-code-500
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219135/mod-rewrite-for-clean-urls-gives-500-internal-server-error
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232907/htaccess-gives-500-error-on-localhost
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-internal-server-error-after-editing-indexphp-file
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-error-after-editing-permalink-options-help

**EDIT :** I think you also check @Lars Rohrbach comment

> tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: It turns out it was a stupid mistake by me in the document.  Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Add `HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe` to your apache config file and restart the apache server. It shows the error details.